# Adding a 'Add/Remove-Tab' functionality to md-tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, tabs, angular-material

my goal is to add functionality to my `md-tabs` control which shall add or remove tabs. I could achieve this easily by adding functionality to e.g. buttons.

The problem is requirements say that this functionality is supposed to lie within the `md-tabs` control itself (not `md-tab-body`!).

So I tried two different approaches:

1. Adding a hardcoded `md-tab`

   ```
   <md-tab ng-repeat="status in statuses">
     <md-tab-label>
       {{status.name}}
       <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">
         {{status.description}}
       </md-tooltip>
     </md-tab-label>
     <md-tab-body>
       <md-button ng-click="removeTab(status)">Remove Tab</md-button>
     </md-tab-body>
   </md-tab>

   <md-tab ng-click="addTab()">
     <md-tab-label> + Add Tab</md-tab-label>
           <md-tab-body>       
     </md-tab-body>
   </md-tab>
   ```

As you can see the `md-tabs`' content is populated via `ng-repeat`, while there is one `md-tab` which is always there. It perfectly fulfils the purpose of adding new tabs to the control.

There is another control, a button within every `md-tab-body` (`removeTabs`) which removes the currently selected tab. While this approach works fine, it has one disadvantge. Every time a tab is removed the tab-selection automatically jumps to the last tab, which is always the `addTab`-Control. This is not what I want! So I tried another approach.

2. Adding tabs via `md-button`

   ```
   <md-tab ng-repeat="status in statuses">
     <md-tab-label>
       {{status.name}}
       <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">
         {{status.description}}
       </md-tooltip>
     </md-tab-label>
     <md-tab-body>
       <md-button ng-click="removeTab(status)">Remove Tab</md-button>
     </md-tab-body>
   </md-tab>

   <md-button ng-click="addTab()"> + Add Tab</md-button>
   ```

While this approach also does fulfil its purpose, it also comes with a disadvantage. Namely the button within the `md-tabs` is being ignored by the control when it comes to adding more tabs. If I add enough tabs they are just being added underneath the button as if it wasn't there.

[image]

While I was thinking I could solve this issue using some css, I was told (in JavaScript chat) not to screw around with `md-tabs` functionality.

[image]

So my overall question here is how to solve this issue. I see two potential solutions here.

1. The `md-tabs`-Control might have some native functionality for such requirements. If it has, I could not find it. Maybe using a custom `md-next`-Control?
2. When using the `md-button` this issue might be solved using css. If this is correct, I am not sure how to tackle this task. Also as I mentioned before, I am wondering if this is a reasonable approach.

For a full examle of my code please reffer to my [Fiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/Kaese/0jkkbfr8/9).

Comment: So after removing the current `tab` you want to go to other specific tab?

Comment: @nextt1 This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the desired `tab` by using `md-selected` attribute. Just define the index of the desired page while removing the `tab`.

Here is the code.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.statuses = [
  {id: 1, name: "One", description: "First Tooltip"},
  {id: 2, name: "Two", description: "Second Tooltip"},
  {id: 3, name: "Three", description: "Third Tooltip"},
 ];
 $scope.selectedTab = 0; //Initial Page 

 $scope.addTab = function(){
  $scope.statuses.push({id: $scope.statuses.length + 1, name: $scope.statuses.length + 1, description: "New Tooltip"});
 }
$scope.removeTab = function(status){
alert(status.id);
$scope.selectedTab = 0; //new line added
var index = $scope.statuses.indexOf(status);
$scope.statuses.splice(index,1);
 }
});
```

HTML Code

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
 <md-tabs class="" md-selected="selectedTab" md-align-tabs="top" md-border-bottom md-autoselect md-dynamic-height>

  <md-tab ng-repeat="status in statuses">
   <md-tab-label>
    {{status.name}}
    <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">
      {{status.description}}
    </md-tooltip>
   </md-tab-label>
   <md-tab-body>
    <md-button ng-click="removeTab(status)">Remove Tab {{selectedTab}}</md-button>
   </md-tab-body>
 </md-tab>

  <md-button style="right: 0;position: absolute;z-index: auto" ng-click="addTab()"> + Add Tab</md-button>
 </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

Here is the working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Next1/ykb50yxa/2/).

Answer (score 0):

This approach is same as yours, The remove button will be in each tab, and add new tab button is outside md-tabs scope and in bottom of page.

```
Try this example in code pen

http://codepen.io/imraqes/pen/jyjKQB
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above the button has to be nested within the md-tabs-Control